# Prove that the operator norm of $~T:L^{p}({\bf R}^{n})\longrightarrow L^{p}({\bf R}^{n})$ is equal to $\|K\|_{L^{1}({\bf R}^{n}~)}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

On ${\bf R}^{n},~$let $T(f)=f*K$ , where $K$ is a positive $L^{1}({\bf R}^{n})$ function and $f$ is in $L^{p}({\bf R}^{n})$ , where $1\le p <\infty$ .Prove that the operator norm of  $~T:L^{p}({\bf R}^{n})\longrightarrow L^{p}({\bf R}^{n})$ is equal to $\|K\|_{L^{1}({\bf R}^{n}~)}$

Here is my proof  :

Clearly, $$\|f*K\|_{L^{p}}\le\|f\|_{L^{p}}\|K\|_{L^{1}}$$

,and hence for each positive $f\in L^{p}({\bf R}^{n})$ , we have  $$\frac{\|f*K\|_{L^{p}}}{\|f\|_{L^{p}}}\le\|K\|_{L^{1}}$$ 
Then , 
$$\|T\|_{L^{p}\rightarrow L^{p}}\le\|K\|_{L^{1}}$$

Conversely, fix an $0<\varepsilon<1$ and let $N$ be a kept natural number.

First we note that for $|x|<(1-\varepsilon)N\Longrightarrow B(0,N\varepsilon)\subseteq B(x,N)$

and then for $|x|<(1-\varepsilon)N,$  $$\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}{\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}(x-y)K{\bf 1}_{B(0,N\varepsilon)}(y)~dy =\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}K{\bf 1}_{B(0,N\varepsilon)}(y)~dy$$

Therefore ,
\begin{align}
\frac{\|K*{\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}\|_{L^{p}}^{p}}{\|{\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}\|_{L^{p}}^{p}}&\ge\bigg(\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}\bigg(\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}K{\bf 1}_{B(0,N\varepsilon)}(y){\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}(x-y)dy\bigg)^{p}dx\bigg)\bigg(\|{\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}\|_{L^{p}}^{p}\bigg)^{-1}\\
&\ge\bigg(\int_{B(0,(1-\varepsilon)N)}\bigg(\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}K{\bf 1}_{B(0,N\varepsilon)}(y){\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}(x-y)dy\bigg)^{p}dx\bigg)\bigg(\|{\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}\|_{L^{p}}^{p}\bigg)^{-1}\\
&=\bigg(\int_{B(0,(1-\varepsilon)N)}\bigg(\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}K{\bf 1}_{B(0,N\varepsilon)}(y)~dy\bigg)^{p}dx\bigg)\bigg(\|{\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}\|_{L^{p}}^{p}\bigg)^{-1}\\
&=\frac{|B(0,(1-\varepsilon)N)|~\|K{\bf 1}_{B(0,N\varepsilon)}\|_{L^{1}}^{p}}{\|{\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}\|_{L^{p}}^{p}}\\
&=\frac{(1-\varepsilon)^{n}|B(0,N)|~\|K{\bf 1}_{B(0,N\varepsilon)}\|_{L^{1}}^{p}}{\|{\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}\|_{L^{p}}^{p}}\\
&=(1-\varepsilon)^{n}\|K{\bf 1}_{B(0,N\varepsilon)}\|_{L^{1}}^{p}
\end{align}
,where the third equality holds by Tonelli's theorem and the fifth holds by $|B(0,N)|=\|{\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}\|_{L^{p}}^{p}$

Thus, we have 
$$\frac{\|K*{\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}\|_{L^{p}}}{\|{\bf 1}_{B(0,N)}\|_{L^{p}}}\ge (1-\varepsilon)^{\frac{n}{p}}\|K{\bf 1}_{B(0,N\varepsilon)}\|_{L^{1}}$$

Consequently , $$\|T\|_{L^{p}\rightarrow L^{p}}\ge (1-\varepsilon)^{\frac{n}{p}}\|K{\bf 1}_{B(0,N\varepsilon)}\|_{L^{1}}$$

,and our conclusions follows if we first take $N\longrightarrow \infty$ and then $\varepsilon\longrightarrow 0.$

Remark : ${\bf 1}_M(x)=1$ if $x\in M$ and ${\bf 1}_M(x)=0$ if $x\notin M$ , which is the so-called Indicator function.

If you have time ,please, check my working for validity . Any suggestion and advice will be the greatest appreciated . Thanks your patient reading and considering my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions. The second  may be more or less what you did.

Say $c_p$ is the norm of $T$ as an operator on $L^p$. Of course it's clear that $c_p\le||K||_1$, the problem is the opposite inequality.

**Proof 1:**

It's clear from Plancherel that $||T||=||\hat K||_\infty$, and of course if $K\ge0$ then $||\hat K||_\infty=||K||_1$.  So $c_2=||K||_1$.

It follows that $c_p=||K||_1$ for all $p$: Say $c_p<||K||_1$ and $1\le p<2$. Since $c_q\le ||K||_1$ for $q>2$, Riesz-Thorin implies that $c_2<||K||_1$. Similarly if $p>2$.

**Proof 2:** Since $||T_1-T_2||\le ||K_1-K_2||_1$ we may assume $K$ has compact support. Write $f_R=\chi_{B(0,R)}$.

Say $K$ is supported in $B(0,R)$. Since $K\ge0$, if $N>R$ then $$K*f_N\ge ||K||_1f_{N-R}.$$ Since $\lim_{N\to\infty}||f_{N-R}||_p/||f_N||_p=1$ it follows that $c_p\ge||K||_1$.

Comment: But such a $K$ with $\|\widehat{K}\|_{\infty}<\|K\|_{1}$ can be nonnegative: $K\geq 0$?

Comment: And one further question: By Plancherel I manage to show that $\|T\|\leq\|\widehat{K}\|_{\infty}$, but how to derive the equality then?

Comment: @user284331 No, if $K\ge0$ then $||\hat K||_\infty=||K||_1$. Sorry, I didn't notice you assumed $k\ge0$. About that other inequality: Say $\epsilon>0$ and let $E=\{\xi:|\hat K(\xi)|>||hat K||_\infty-\epsilon\}$. By definition of $||\hat K||_\infty$, $m(E)>0$. Say $F\subset E$ with $0<m(F)<\infty$, and consider $f$ with $\hat f=\chi_F$.

Comment: @user284331 Don't miss the new version...